# PowerMock not creating mock for new final object instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am writing an unit test for method that instantiates final class like this:

```
    public Mono<String> getSecret(String key) {
        SecretClientBuilder secretClientBuilder = new SecretClientBuilder();
        secretClientBuilder = secretClientBuilder.vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl);
        secretClientBuilder = secretClientBuilder.credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build());
        SecretClient secretClient = secretClientBuilder.buildClient();
        KeyVaultSecret retrievedSecret = secretClient.getSecret(key);
        return Mono.just(retrievedSecret.getValue());
    }
```

`SecretClient` and `SecretClientBuilder` are imported from azure library. In order to test this, I am trying to use `PowerMockito`

My approach is to create mock object when `new SecretClientBuilder()` is called so when that mock object is calling methods such as `.vaultUrl()` or `.credential()`, I can make my test to return a mocked objects. Here is my starting code:

```
    @Before
    public void before() {
        keyVaultService = new KeyVaultServiceImpl(KEY_VAULT_URL);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        SecretClientBuilder secretClientBuilder = mock(SecretClientBuilder.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SecretClientBuilder.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(secretClientBuilder);
        PowerMockito.when(secretClientBuilder.vaultUrl(anyString())).thenReturn(secretClientBuilder);
        keyVaultService.getSecret(CLIENT_ID_KEY);
    }
```

However, test fails because when `SecretClientBuilder` is being instantiated, it does not return the mock object. Instead, it creates a new instance of `SecretClientBuilder` when `SecretClientBuilder secretClientBuilder = new SecretClientBuilder()`.

How can I instantiate `SecretClientBuilder` object using PowerMockito? **`SecretClientBuilder` is final class.**

Edit:
This is what I am using for class annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({KeyVaultService.class, SecretClientBuilder.class})
```

I tried only using either classes in `@PrepareForTest` and nothing works with same behavior.

Edit2: I was testing with `TestService` to see if final was an issue. It was not. Here is my TestService:

```
public class TestService {
    
    public String test() {
        return "actual";
    }
```

and here is my KeyVaultService:

```
    public Mono<String> getSecret(String key) {
        TestService testService = new TestService();
        System.out.println(testService.test());
        ...
    }
```

and my test:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        TestService mock = mock(TestService.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(TestService .class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mock);
        PowerMockito.when(mock.test()).thenReturn("mock");
        keyVaultService.getSecret(CLIENT_ID_KEY);//should print "mock"
    }
```

But it prints "actual" meaning mocked object was never created when `new TestService();` was called. Is my understanding of PowerMockito and whenNew wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Leaving this for anybody who is having some issue.

Problem was that I was adding interface class not actual implementation class. **Changing `@PrepareForTest(KeyVaultService.class)` to `@PrepareForTest(KeyVaultServiceImpl.class)`** works.